# http get request with array using rxjs

Tags: json, angular, http, rxjs

`this.data` is an array of `json` objects and I am simply trying to find a way to parse the individual objects (in this case just printing to console will do)
the data after in the method `getData()` properly. Both of these methods return observables in the forms `this.http.put` and `this.http.get`

```
this.persistanceData.setData(this.data)
              .subscribe((res: any) => { });

this.persistentDataService.getData()
              .map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe(data => data.map(item => console.log(item)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular 2+ we are handling two kind of ayncs events.They are **Promise and Observables**.

Promise can handle **single async task** whereas Observables can handle **multiple events**.

If you're handling multiple events you need to use Observables.

Import Observable on your provider like below.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
```

Depending on the task you could change the rxjs operator.

In this case, we're going to change the response into json.

```
getData():Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('192.168.1.1:8081/users/user_id=1')
    .map((response:Response) =>response.json())
}
```

Above method simply returns the response as **JSON** and no need to change the response into **json()** in pages or components.

Any queries to use Observable please use this link https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables

Comment: works well for json objects, but not an array of objects as in [ {..}, {...} ]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Angular 2, there is no use for **.pipe()** and the imports are different for earlier versions of **rxjs 6**

Your getData() function should look something like that in your **persistentDataService**:

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
  let baseURL = 'http://your-url';
  return this.http.get(apiURL) 
      .map(res => { return res.json(); });
}
```

You should of course import the following in your service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Then, you can go back to your component and manage the returned Observable and subscribe to init (**ngOnInit** for example):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.persistentDataService.getData()
              .subscribe(data => console.log(data)))
}
```

Do not forget to Inject your service in your constructor, to implement OnInit interface and to install rxjs version below 6.

Comment: I think i have angular 2 if that makes a difference. I am getting errors with pipe however (it doesnt recognize map)

Comment: It matters. Edited.

Comment: works well for json objects, but not an array of objects as in [ {..}, {...} ]